# activeSyle for index is always true in Gatsby-link

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I've encountered a problem that I've tried to solve without success. activeStyle works except the fact that Home or "/" is always active when switching to another page like "/about". Anyone have a solution for this? Or anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong?

The file below is the index layout - the common markup for all pages in my Gatsby project. Thankful for help.

```
import React from "react"
import Link from "gatsby-link"
import styles from "./index.module.css";
console.log(styles);

const ListLink = props =>
  <li style={{ display: `inline-block`, marginRight: `1rem` }}>
    <Link to={props.to} activeStyle={{ color: 'yellow' }}>
      {props.children}
    </Link>
  </li>

export default ({ children }) => (
    <div className={styles.container}>
        <div className={styles.sidebar}>
            <Link to="/">
                <h1>Header</h1>
            </Link>
            <ul className={styles.nav}>
                <ListLink to="/">Home</ListLink>
                <ListLink to="/about/">About</ListLink>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.main}>
            {children()}
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

[SOLVED]

Added *exact* to `<Link exact to={props.to} activeStyle={{ color: 'yellow' }}>`. Now it works perfect.

Comment: When you say that Home or root `"/"` is always active when switching to another page, you mean that you can simultaneously see the `/about` page and the `/` root route or home page rendering in the browser?

Comment: I can see the content for /about and everything else works except that when I'm on the, for example, /about page it is active (as it should be) but the root is also active.. thanks for your reply @Daniel

Comment: I am still not 100% clear if fully understand, but it sounds like you just ran into a react-router gotcha, but before I jump to conclusions. Are you indeed using `react-router`? Would you mind posting your route configuration above?

Comment: @AlexS Glad you figured it out! Could you answer your own question and accept it as the correct answer (to help other users with the same question, making the answer a little easier to discover)? Thank you! ✌️

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Added **exact** to `<Link exact to={props.to} activeStyle={{ color: 'yellow' }}>`. It should work then!